# Preparing USB drive for Kali Linux

Tags: filesystems, system-installation, live-usb, kali-linux

I'm new to Kali Linux. I want to install it on my PC which is already running windows 8. I know how to dual boot a PC.

I'll be booting Linux from a USB device, but while creating a bootable USB drive, which file system should I choose? NTFS or FAT32 for the Kali Linux ISO file?

Comment: Did you sort it out?

Answer (score 5):

If you just copy the .iso file to FAT32 or NTFS formatted USB drive, you will **NOT** be able to boot from it. So in short: You do not need to chose any file system, nor format your drive the way you are doing it. Before you start the drive can be any filesystem (NTFS or FAT32).

You need wirte .iso file to USB. For this you can use Win32DiskImager https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer

More information on how to properly prepare Kali Live USB: http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-live-usb-install

Answer (score 0):

I have found that just by making your usb FAT32 and copying the ISO to the FAT32. You **CAN** boot the Kali USB for ***the first time***.

Then the Kali will immediately change the signature of the FAT32 partition to RAW.

So when you shutdown the live Kali and boot back to Windows, you'll see your stick showed as RAW.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the FS prior to writing the image on a flash drive, it's hit or miss for me. I've done it NTFS, FAT32, vfat, unallocated, used unetbootin, Rufus, DD... sometimes it works, and sometimes it don't. That's been my experience